# Is it possible to override String.split function in Salesforce Apex?

Tags: apex, string, split

I want to override split function of String class with one more parameter.
Is it possible?

```
String s = 'aKey:aValue::bKey:bValue::cKey:cValue';
Map<String, String> mapS = s.split(':', 0, '::');

//something like .. 
//String.split(String primarySeparator, Integer limit, String secondarySeparator)
```

If not can I create custom function in String class?

Answer (score 6):

No. The Apex language has no support for what other languages might call mixins or categories. You can only subclass and extend classes declared `virtual` or `abstract`, which the system's `String` class is not.

Your functionality must go in one of your own classes.

See [Apex Class Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm) for a bit more detail on what you can do in defining an Apex class.